# Date to Timestamp Help required

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using jQuery DatePicker to select from date and to date. when I select a date i covert it to timestamp using strtotime function, I have some dates stored in my database with column type timestamp.

when I convert the selected date from date picker using strtotime

```
 $from_date = strtotime($form['from-date']);
```

it gives me something like this

```
   1338508800
```

while the date stored in my database table looks like this

```
2012-06-09 02:24:25
```

I want to query the records on the basis of the selected from and to date. but the query is not getting my dates correctly.

How can I change the selected date so that it give me results in between the two selected dates?

Comment: oops missed that, but you've specified it is `timestamp` (in the second question line)

Comment: @zerkms I converted it to date to keep things simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($form['from-date']));`